# mysql - conditional 'on clause' in mysql join

Tags: mysql

I try to establish a conditional 'on clause' in a mysql join.

If field1 is not empty, this should be used in the 'on claus',
but if empty, field2 instead should be used.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
JOIN table2

IF (field1!='') THEN (
    ON  table1.field1 = table2.field1
    AND table1.field3 = table2.field3
    )
ELSE (
    ON  table1.field2 = table2.field2
    AND table1.field3 = table2.field3
    )
END IF
```

Any idea if this is possible on how it could be done?

Edit:
I forgot to explain that both tables contain empty fields and I try to prevent that mysql uses these fields for the join, as that gives a (very) lot of joins, so my idea should be more like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
JOIN table2

IF (table1.field1!='' AND table2.field1!='') THEN (
    ON  table1.field1 = table2.field1
    AND table1.field3 = table2.field3
    )
ELSE (
    ON  table1.field2 = table2.field2
    AND table1.field3 = table2.field3
    )
END IF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table2 t3
on t1.Field1=t2.Field1 and t1.Field3=t2.Field3
on t1.Field2=t3.Field2 and t1.Field3=t3.Field3
```

Then use a condition tho choose the field from table2 or table3.

Hope this helps you.

**EDIT**

To select the right field use this:

```
SELECT t1.*, IF(t2.field1 is null, t3.field1, t2.Field1) as Field1
```

Comment: The condition should be placed in the where clause, is that right?

Comment: No. In the select. I Edit my answer

Comment: Currently I get " Unknown column 't2.Field1' in 'on clause' "

Comment: Try t1.field1. Could be upper case related.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider converting your `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` as already shown in other answer like

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
     LEFT JOIN table2 t2
     ON t1.field1 = t2.field1 AND t1.field3 = t2.field3
     LEFT JOIN table2 t22
     ON t1.field2 = t22.field2 AND t1.field3 = t22.field3
```

You can as well try something like below

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.field1 = t2.field1 AND t1.field3 = t2.field3 
       OR t1.field2 = t2.field2 AND t1.field3 = t2.field3
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON 
     (
        (table1.field1 = '' AND table1.field2 = table2.field2 AND table1.field3 = table2.field3) 
        OR 
        (table1.field1 != '' AND table1.field1 = table2.field1 AND table1.field3 = table2.field3)
     )
```

(note: I have no idea how efficient or otherwise this approach is)